# Run app as administrator on logon of non-administrative user accounts

Tags: windows, uac, windows-task-scheduler

We need a program / application to open with local administrative permissions (Process Monitor, so it's non-negotiable) on logon of any given (including non-administrative) user account.

Task Scheduler seems to be the way to go with this but I'm having major problems bypassing the UAC prompt:

1. Option `When running this task, use the following user account` seems to determine which user account / profile the process will run under so:
   1a. Using `Administrator`, `SYSTEM`, etc doesn't work as required.
   1b. Using `Users` does work but...
2. Logged on as a non-administrative user account, option `Run with the highest privileges` does prompt for credentials but fails due to insufficient permissions to save the task.
3. Logged on as an administrative user account, option `Run with the highest privileges` doesn't prompt for credentials and, as such, the app opens with a UAC prompt on logon of a non-administrative user account.

Not duplicates of:

1. [Force a program to run *without* administrator privileges or UAC?](https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac) or [How to launch a GUI Windows application with administrator rights without asking for the pasword from the user?](https://superuser.com/questions/610482/how-to-launch-a-gui-windows-application-with-administrator-rights-without-asking?rq=1) because the app must actually run with administrative permissions.
2. [How can I run ALL my Apps “as administrator” by default in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/204781/how-can-i-run-all-my-apps-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-7/873697#873697) or [Run applications as administrator by default in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1002262/run-applications-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-10?rq=1) because only this app must be run with administrative permissions.

Comment: I was complaining about the question I flagged as a duplicate's title not the title of your question

Comment: possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/204781/how-can-i-run-all-my-apps-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-7/873697#873697 and https://superuser.com/questions/1002262/run-applications-as-administrator-by-default-in-windows-10?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/610482/how-to-launch-a-gui-windows-application-with-administrator-rights-without-asking?rq=1

Comment: that is not possible for standard users, the task scheduler trick only works for admin accounts which gets 2 tokens

Comment: the edit makes no diff, the task scheduler trick doesn't work for normal standard users